# Fraction to exact decimal

Tags: code-golf, number, rational-numbers, restricted-time

Write a program or function that given two integers *a, b* outputs a string containing a decimal number representing the fraction *a/b* **exactly**.

If *a/b* is integer, simply output the value, without a decimal dot or leading zeroes:

```
123562375921304812375087183597 / 2777 -> 44494913907563850333124661
81 / 3 -> 27
-6 / 2 -> -3
```

If *a/b* is not integer but has a finite representation in base 10, output the value without leading or trailing zeroes (except a single zero before the dot):

```
1 / 2 -> 0.5
3289323463 / -250000000 -> -13.157293852
```

Finally, if **and only if** (so no `0.999...`) *a/b* is not integer and does not have a finite representation, output the finite part followed by the repeating part in parenthesis. The repeating part must be as small as possible, and start as early as possible.

```
-1 / 3 -> -0.(3)
235 / 14 -> 16.7(857142)
123 / 321 -> 0.(38317757009345794392523364485981308411214953271028037)
355 / 113 -> 3.(1415929203539823008849557522123893805309734513274336283185840707964601769911504424778761061946902654867256637168)
```

---

Your program must work for all above examples in under 10 seconds on a modern desktop PC. Smallest program in bytes wins.

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon This is possible in pretty much *all* languages, including Turing tarpits. (Those might struggle with the time limit though.)

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon I was under the impression that most languages are turing complete.

Comment: Can we safely assume the fraction won't be something like: 0.33333333333336333...?

Comment: @brianush1 Of course not. There is only one exact answer for a fraction, and your answer must correctly determine that one answer.

Comment: Is this possible on real tangible computers (limited memory)?

Comment: This seems like a long-winded way of asking for solutions to [PE26](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26) ;)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien The general case is a tad more complicated than the reciprocal case. To emphasize, there was one incorrect example in my initial post due to this, and I still haven't found the bug in my test program...

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon It is possible with limited memory. You would only need memory up to the point where the decimal starts repeating. So assuming you do the worst and store a binary digit per byte, you'd still only use max 1KB

Comment: Can b be negative? (Edit: Never mind, just saw the test case where it is)

Comment: Generalisation of [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78850/194); [also related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49608/194).

Comment: Is the input format literally a pair of integers, or is it already in the form "a / b" with the "/" included?

Comment: @GregMartin Whatever you prefer.

Comment: Also very similar to this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22146/implement-arbitrary-precision-division

Comment: I recall this exact question from USACO's site (same output format as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>63 58</s>  50 bytes

```perl6
{->$a,$b {$a~"($b)"x?$b}(|($^a.FatRat/$^b).base-repeating(10))}
```

```perl6
{->\a,$b {a~"($b)"x?$b}(|($^a.FatRat/$^b).base-repeating)}
```

```perl6
{$/=($^a.FatRat/$^b).base-repeating;$0~"($1)"x?$1}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#xVLLbtswELzzK4hAaChUkrkPcskYTnPqBxQ9p1ActTDqOoYtBwnS9NfTVWQ7vrSHXqrTcjQ7s0vObtvZ@9jMp2an1edu20@N@fFo383vbjs7e3kqJjNXXLfNx7b/1PaT4vqmbG7abVdvunXX9ovVt2nhf525Asqzhw8FPL9o91WvQls7s85Y6wApRCQJGYE8JxhqnwQShSwVikhpZ5f2nJkzZ6DsJURKwRMRIMcI59UglKCikYkyInWscERqGhE4AL4JI0KYMiFxpKrG4Mdv3wTUQBDMaoZ7xaNH7RtH5YjqBhXwiENsxKUgwLj/qwtVhHDwdZQIRIJ4n4mDZKaMAYkicwo56SUkBkDgHAgFPCZPsteioE6wH4EaBwx6bxk9BcoJyfuUtC9IQFRfXS35QD6LOoGqsdqg@qeQ2IuXHDl6kJgzQPDMyCJJIvgImWP2GAOnKBhiJIGYhjFKzcB62a7s@/Eh9fj1bnN41frSFl@ssxffu0d3tVitd31Z2Yv7drnrXNE9rLt5392WtrRPutBia4couZ9H5pFyUjbrbrM0zy9/j4qd2CEswwR/jopJoDwaSCimjkPTcKjJGDgcNBzmLReKviXjlXuaC2Pqo@KYCaNTKgI8QKdxMDrvQEUYTf4xCUZDMOjDq@f/CMFv)

If you don't care that it will only work with denominators that fit into a 64 bit integer it can be shortened to just 43 bytes:

```perl6
{$/=($^a/$^b).base-repeating;$0~"($1)"x?$1}
```

#### Expanded:

```perl6
{
  # store in match variable so that we can
  # use ｢$0｣ and ｢$1｣
  $/ = (

    # turn the first value into a FatRat so that
    # it will continue to work for all Int inputs
    $^a.FatRat / $^b

  ).base-repeating;

  # ｢$0｣ is short for ｢$/[0]｣ which is the non-repeating part
  $0

  # string concatenated with
  ~

  # string repeat once if $1 is truthy (the repeating part)
  # otherwise it will be an empty Str
  "($1)" x ?$1
}
```

Comment: The way you formatted your answer is confusing. You should remove your old programs, because right now it looks like a multi-line program.

Comment: @mbomb007 The main reason I have for posting golfs is for marketing, and education of Perl 6. So I leave old versions in to show more of the language. That's also why I rarely post one until I have some sort of explanation in there. I have altered it so that the different examples are in different code blocks.

Comment: Old versions are always visible in the post's edit history.

Comment: @mbomb007 Not if I wait to post until after trying several different ways to write it.

Comment: Then just edit one in every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2, 174 bytes

```py
x,y=input()
a=abs(x)
b=abs(y)
r=a%b*10
L=[]
M=''
while~-(r in L):L+=r,;M+=str(r/b);r=r%b*10
i=L.index(r)
t=M[:i]+"(%s)"%M[i:]*(M[i:]>'0')
print"-%d."[x*y>=0:(t>'')+3]%(a/b)+t
```

I'm not quite convinced about the validity of this answer, but it's worked for the test cases above and other test cases I've thrown at it. It looks like a right mess though, so I'm sure there's plenty of room for golfing.

The initial setup takes absolute values of both arguments to ensure that we're dealing with nonnegative numbers (saving the sign calculation for later), and delegates the quotient part of the result to Python's arbitrary precision arithmetic. The fractional part is done with the grade-school division algorithm until we get a repeat in the remainder. We then look up when we last saw this repeat in order to get the period, and construct the string accordingly.

Note that the algorithm's actually quite slow due to the O(n) `in` operation, but it's fast enough for the examples.

Answer (score 5):

### Batch, <s>349</s> 344 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ad=%2,i=%1/d,r=%1%%d
if not %r%==0 set i=%i%.&if %r% leq 0 set/ar=-r&if %i%==0 set i=-0.
set d=%d:-=%
set/ae=d
:g
if %r%==0 echo %i%&exit/b
set/ag=-~!(e%%2)*(!(e%%5)*4+1)
if not %g%==1 set/ae/=g&call:d&goto g
set/as=r
set i=%i%(
:r
call:d
if %r%==%s% echo %i%)&exit/b
goto r
:d
set/ar*=10,n=r/d,r%%=d
set i=%i%%n%
```

Edit: Saved 5 bytes by removing unnecessary characters. "Ungolfed":

```
@echo off
set /a d = %2
set /a i = %1 / d
set /a r = %1 % d
if not %r%==0 (
    set i=%i%.                  Decimal point is required
    if %r% leq 0 (
        set /a r = -r           Get absolute value of remainder
        if %i%==0 set i=-0.     Fix edge case (-1/3 = 0 remainder -1)
    )
)
set d = %d:-=%                  Get absolute value of divisor
set /a e = d
:g
if %r%==0 echo %i% & exit /b    Finished if there's no remainder
set /a g = gcd(e, 10)           Loop through nonrecurring decimals
if not %g%==1 (
    set /a e /= g
    call :d
    goto g
)
set /a s = r                    Save remainder to know when loop ends
set i=%i%(
:r
call :d
if %r%==%s% echo %i%)&exit/b
goto r
:d                              Add the next decimal place
set /a r *= 10
set /a n = r / d
set /a r %= d
set i=%i%%n%
```

Comment: I have no idea how any of this works, but I commend you for doing it in batch lmao

Comment: I'm impressed with the capabilities of `set /a`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <strike>625</strike> 605

Golfed code:

```java
import static java.math.BigInteger.*;
String f(BigInteger a, BigInteger b){BigInteger[]r=a.divideAndRemainder(b);String s=r[0].toString();if(r[1].signum()<0)s="-"+s;if(!ZERO.equals(r[1])){s+='.';List<BigInteger>x=new ArrayList();List<BigInteger>y=new ArrayList();for(BigInteger d=TEN.multiply(r[1].abs());;){BigInteger[]z=d.divideAndRemainder(b.abs());int i=y.indexOf(z[1]);if(i>-1&&i==x.indexOf(z[0])){for(int j=0;j<i;++j)s+=x.get(j);s+='(';for(int j=i;j<x.size();++j)s+=x.get(j);s+=')';break;}x.add(z[0]);y.add(z[1]);if(ZERO.equals(z[1])){for(BigInteger j:x)s+=j;break;}d=TEN.multiply(z[1]);}}return s;}
```

Note: I count the static import as part of the function for golfing purposes.

This function starts out by getting the division result. It adds the integral portion and sign, if necessary. Then if there is a remainder, it performs base 10 long division. At each step, perform the division. Store the calculated digit and the remainder in two lists. If we encounter the same digit and remainder again, there is a repeated portion and we know what index it starts at. The code either adds the digits (no repeat) or the pre-repeat digits, then the repeated digits enclosed in parentheses.

This is a bit big mostly because of `BigInteger`. If the inputs did not overflow even a `long` then it could be a bit shorter. Still, I expect there are ways to improve this entry.

Ungolfed code with main method for testing:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.math.BigInteger.*;

public class FractionToExactDecimal {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // @formatter:off
    String[][] testData = new String[][] {
      { "123562375921304812375087183597", "2777", "44494913907563850333124661" },
      { "81", "3", "27" },
      { "-6", "2", "-3" },
      { "1", "2", "0.5" },
      { "3289323463", "-250000000", "-13.157293852" },
      { "-1", "3", "-0.(3)" },
      { "235", "14", "16.7(857142)" },
      { "123", "321", "0.(38317757009345794392523364485981308411214953271028037)" },
      { "355", "113", "3.(1415929203539823008849557522123893805309734513274336283185840707964601769911504424778761061946902654867256637168)" }
    };
    // @formatter:on

    for (String[] data : testData) {
      System.out.println(data[0] + " / " + data[1]);
      System.out.println("  Expected -> " + data[2]);
      System.out.print("    Actual -> ");
      System.out.println(new FractionToExactDecimal().f(new BigInteger(data[0]), new BigInteger(data[1])));
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  // Begin golf
  String f(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    BigInteger[] r = a.divideAndRemainder(b);
    String s = r[0].toString();
    if (r[1].signum() < 0) s = "-" + s;
    if (!ZERO.equals(r[1])) {
      s += '.';
      List<BigInteger> x = new ArrayList();
      List<BigInteger> y = new ArrayList();
      for (BigInteger d = TEN.multiply(r[1].abs());;) {
        BigInteger[] z = d.divideAndRemainder(b.abs());
        int i = y.indexOf(z[1]);
        if (i > -1 && i == x.indexOf(z[0])) {
          for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            s += x.get(j);
          s += '(';
          for (int j = i; j < x.size(); ++j)
            s += x.get(j);
          s += ')';
          break;
        }
        x.add(z[0]);
        y.add(z[1]);
        if (ZERO.equals(z[1])) {
          for (BigInteger j : x)
            s += j;
          break;
        }
        d = TEN.multiply(z[1]);
      }
    }
    return s;
  }
  // End golf
}
```

Program output:

```
123562375921304812375087183597 / 2777
  Expected -> 44494913907563850333124661
    Actual -> 44494913907563850333124661

81 / 3
  Expected -> 27
    Actual -> 27

-6 / 2
  Expected -> -3
    Actual -> -3

1 / 2
  Expected -> 0.5
    Actual -> 0.5

3289323463 / -250000000
  Expected -> -13.157293852
    Actual -> -13.157293852

-1 / 3
  Expected -> -0.(3)
    Actual -> -0.(3)

235 / 14
  Expected -> 16.7(857142)
    Actual -> 16.7(857142)

123 / 321
  Expected -> 0.(38317757009345794392523364485981308411214953271028037)
    Actual -> 0.(38317757009345794392523364485981308411214953271028037)

355 / 113
  Expected -> 3.(1415929203539823008849557522123893805309734513274336283185840707964601769911504424778761061946902654867256637168)
    Actual -> 3.(1415929203539823008849557522123893805309734513274336283185840707964601769911504424778761061946902654867256637168)
```

Comment: Nice! I think you can save a few bytes by making this a function that returns a string, and by removing that one space in `a, BigInteger`. I also think you could alias `BigInteger.TEN` and `BigInteger.ZERO`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks, I didn't realize the static import saved space over the more verbose references. It does. I also found a few other things I had missed, such as `while (true)` -> `for (;;)` which also allowed me to put stuff in the `for` initializer, saving another byte.

Comment: First, how about extending BigInteger? Second, a repeated remainder is enough to show it repeats; if you limit the input to int you can use an int[] with the remainder as index and the index as value, if that makes sense.

Comment: @JollyJoker extending BigInteger would require writing a whole class to try to save space, and I seriously doubt the tradeoff would work. Plus, I _cannot_ restrict input. Anyway, there are eight instances of the text `BigInteger` in my code, and I don't see how adding more code to shrink them to a single character class name will pay off. And certainly adding code to deal with `int[]` (which BigInteger already does internally) will only bloat my answer.

Comment: @JollyJoker it is also worth mentioning that unless I override _every_ `BigInteger` method I call to return an instance of the subclass, I will need to add several casts which further bloat the code. On top of the wasted bytes for a subclass's overhead, that would certainly increase the code size.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of the casts. Where in the question does it say the input can be arbitrarily long though? Wouldn't a method taking two ints and returning a String be a valid answer?

Comment: @JollyJoker integer length is unspecified, but consider "Your program must work for all above examples" and "123562375921304812375087183597". That number is 97 bits, which overflows all integer primitives in Java. Therefore, a Java program _must_ use `BigInteger` or an equivalent class to handle those numbers. Since `BigInteger` is built into the JFC, it requires no extra code in a golf program. I will stick with that for golfing.

Comment: I'll try to find a spot on ...sunday? when I have more than 5 mins free in front of a computer to write down a solution :)

Comment: Does `BigInteger a, BigInteger b`=>`BigInteger a,BigInteger b` work?

Comment: @Zacharý yes, that works. However, short of some other trick to reduce byte count substantially, it is not worth changing it.

Comment: You can golf it to 555 bytes: `import java.math.*;import java.util.*;String f(BigInteger a,BigInteger b){BigInteger r[]=a.divideAndRemainder(b),d,z[];String s=r[0]+"";if(r[1].signum()<0)s="-"+s;if(!a.ZERO.equals(r[1])){s+='.';List<BigInteger>x=new Stack(),y=new Stack();for(d=a.TEN.multiply(r[1].abs());;){z=d.divideAndRemainder(b.abs());int i=y.indexOf(z[1]),j;if(i>-1&i==x.indexOf(z[0])){for(j=0;j<i;)s+=x.get(j++);s+='(';for(j=i;j<x.size();)s+=x.get(j++);s+=')';break;}x.add(z[0]);y.add(z[1]);if(a.ZERO.equals(z[1])){for(BigInteger k:x)s+=k;break;}d=a.TEN.multiply(z[1]);}}return s;}`.

Comment: [Try it here.](https://tinyurl.com/ycvgxsmq) It does seem to fail for some tests that aren't part of the test cases, like `1/6` (expected `0.1(6)`) or `1/7` (expected `0.(142857)`). Not sure why, though..

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 277 Bytes

```
list(,$n,$d)=$argv;$a[]=$n;$n-=$d*$r[]=$n/$d^0;!$n?:$r[]=".";while($n&&!$t){$n*=10;$n-=$d*$r[]=$n/$d^0;$t=in_array($n%=$d,$a);$a[]=$n;}if($t){$l=count($a)-($p=array_search(end($a),$a));echo join(array_slice($r,0,2+$p))."(".join(array_slice($r,2+$p,$l)).")";}else echo join($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 198 bytes

```
i=Integer;t=ToString;a_~h~b_:=f[a/b];f@q_i:= t@q;
f@q_:=""<>{t@IntegerPart[q],".",RealDigits[FractionalPart[q]][[1]]//.{{x___,{k__i}}:> {x,"("<>(t/@{k})<>")"},{x__i,j___String}:>""<> {""<>t/@{x},j}}}
```

---

### UnGolfed

```
(* hand over quotient of a, b to function f *)
h[a_, b_] := f[a/b];

(* if the quotient is an integer, return it as a string *)
f[q_Integer] := ToString@q;

(* otherwise, return the integer part, followed by a decimal point ...*)
f[q_] := "" <> {ToString@IntegerPart[q], ".", 

   (* replacing the repeating part (if it exists) between parentheses *)
   RealDigits[FractionalPart[q]][[1]] //. {{x___, {i__Integer}} :> {x, "(" <>(ToString /@ {i}) <> ")"},

   (* and the non-repeating part (if it exists) without parentheses *)
   {x__Integer, i___String} :> "" <> {"" <> ToString /@ {x}, i}}}
```

---

### Tests

```
h @@@ {{81, 3}, {-81, 3}, {1, 4}, {-13, 3}, {19, 7}, {3289323463, 25000}, {235, 14}, {1325, 14}}
```

{"27", "-27", "0.25", "-4.(3)", "2.(714285)", "131572.93852",
"16.7(857142)", "94.6(428571)"}